# IMAPLIB XML attachments not detected

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, imap, imaplib

The following code doesn't consider there is an attachment if the attachment is with the extension .XLS but in XML format. I am using IMAPLIB and everything works fine except when the attachment is an XML spreadsheet.

```
for self.i in tqdm(range(latest_email_id, oldest_email_id - 1, -1)):
        print("Incrementation:",self.i)
        #x = mail[i-1]
        status = ""
        xdeleted = False
        typ, x = self.m.fetch(str(self.i), '(RFC822)')
        raw_email = x[0][1]
        raw_email_string = raw_email.decode()
        email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

        for response_part in x:
            if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
                msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1].decode())
        #print(x.senton.date())
        #sentondate = pd.to_datetime(x.senton.date())

        senderemail = msg['from']
        subject = msg['subject'].replace("\n","").replace("\r","")
        datemsg = msg["Date"]
        subject, encoding = email.header.decode_header(subject)[0]
        if (encoding == None):
            subject = subject
        else:
            subject = subject.decode(encoding)

        print("subject:", subject)
        print("Date:", datemsg)
        attachmentsfilenamesconcat = ""
        attachments = []
        for part in email_message.walk():
            if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
                continue
            if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                continue
            fileName, encoding = decode_header(str(part.get_filename()))[0]
            if (encoding is None):
                fileName = fileName.replace("\r","").replace("\n","")
            else:
                fileName = fileName.decode(encoding).replace("\r","").replace("\n","")

            attachments.append(fileName)
            if bool(fileName):
                fnwoext, file_extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.join(self.DIR_ATT, fileName))
                if ((file_extension.lower() == ".csv") | (file_extension.lower() == ".xls") | (
                        file_extension.lower() == ".xlsx") \
                        | (file_extension.lower() == ".xlsm") | (file_extension.lower() == ".pdf") | (
                                file_extension.lower() == ".zip") \
                        | (file_extension.lower() == ".txt")):
                    print(os.path.join(self.DIR_ATT, fileName))

                    filePath = os.path.join(self.DIR_ATT,fileName)
                    fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
                    fp.write(part.get_payload(decode = True))
                    fp.close()
```

Any ideas of which syntax to use to detect those attachments?

Comment: What is this `|`?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Logical Or?

Comment: If you want to work with mailbox instead RFC, try https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Comment: `|` is _bitwise_ `or`; in Python logical or is `or`.

Comment: Maybe it doesn’t have a content-disposition header?

Comment: @Max not sure what that means, before porting my script to imaplib I was using pywin32 and the attachment was detected...

Comment: `if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
                continue`
You're skipping any parts without a content disposition header.  Attachments don't necessarily have one.